# Как из простого массива получить ассоциативный с присвоением пары ключ=>значение?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть простой массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Мужской
    [1] => Женский
)
```

из него, мне необходимо получить ассоциативный массив следующего вида

```
Array 
( [0] => Array 
      (
      [id] => 0
      [data] = Мужской
      )
  [1] => Array 
      (
      [id] => 1
      [data] = Женский
      )
)
```

Перебрал кучу вариантов из php мануала, но нужного результата добиться не смог, подскажите как правильно составить функцию для построения такого ассоциативного массива.

Спасибо всем за ответы!!! 
Результатом работы скрипта целиком, является выгрузка значений ENUM из базы данных MySQL.
Вот такой скрипт у меня получился:

```
<?php
/**
* Запрос ENUM данных 
**/

function get_enum_values() {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT SUBSTRING(COLUMN_TYPE,5) 
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA='jg' AND TABLE_NAME='users'
    AND COLUMN_NAME='sex'";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $enum = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $enum = $row;   
    }
    return $enum;

$enum_arr = get_enum_values();
$enum_arr = explode("','", trim(implode($enum_arr), "'()"));
$new_enum_arr = [];

foreach ($enum_arr as $id => $data) {
    $new_enum_arr[] = ['id' => $id, 'data' => $data];
}
var_dump($new_enum_arr);
?>
```

Использовал вариант из ответа № 2 потому, что для меня, он оказался самым простым в понимании.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пройтись в цикле по существующему массиву, и собрать новый:

```
$array = ['Мужской', 'Женский'];
$new_array = [];

foreach ($array as $id => $sex) {
    $new_array[] = ['id' => $id, 'data' => $sex];
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Способ №1:**

```
$array = ['Мужской', 'Женский'];
foreach ($array as $id => &$value) {
    $value = ['id' => $id, 'data' => $value];
}
var_dump($array);
```

**Способ №2:**

```
$array = ['Мужской', 'Женский'];
array_walk($array, function(&$v, $k) { $v = ['id' => $k, 'data' => $v]; });
var_dump($array);
```